# "event-calendar" gem with mongoid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, mongoid

I want to use 'event_calendar' in my rails application. My application is configured for mongoid instead of ActiveRecord. So How can I use this gem in my rails application? When I use event_calendar by following https://github.com/elevation/event_calendar links tutorial I got follwoing error:

```
undefined local variable or method `has_event_calendar' for Event:Class
```

Please help me, how to solve this problem? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

why don't you try [simple_calendar](https://github.com/excid3/simple_calendar)?
seems to be more flexible than event-calendar...besides, event-calendar's last commit was 2 years ago, this gem is obsolete

Comment: I want to handle event like google calendar, dose simple_calendar support this feature?

Comment: I guess so...look this: http://excid3.com/blog/rails-tip-6-simple-calendar-for-rails-3/ you can customize the calendar too